# SPSS bizarre glitch when importing from excel

Tags: excel, import, spss

I am trying to run down the source of a bizzare data glitch I am getting in SPSS. when I import my data, the cases for every other line (all the odds from 33-63) in column 2 show up blank (not missing, but blank). After 65 that it starts showing 3 blanks in a row, then a record, then 3 more blanks and so on up to 100 records (the file ends at 100 records.)

It looks like this:

```
N   ID_1    F_Name  L_Name  ID_2
1   ABC1    First   Last    p1234567
2   ABC2    First   Last    p1234567
3   ABC3    First   Last    p1234567
4   ABC4    First   Last    p1234567
5   ABC5    First   Last    p1234567
6   ABC6    First   Last    p1234567
7   ABC7    First   Last    p1234567
8   ABC8    First   Last    p1234567
9   ABC9    First   Last    p1234567
10  ABC10   First   Last    p1234567
11  ABC11   First   Last    p1234567
12  ABC12   First   Last    p1234567
13  ABC13   First   Last    p1234567
14  ABC14   First   Last    p1234567
15  ABC15   First   Last    p1234567
16  ABC16   First   Last    p1234567
17  ABC17   First   Last    p1234567
18  ABC18   First   Last    p1234567
19  ABC19   First   Last    p1234567
20  ABC20   First   Last    p1234568
21  ABC21   First   Last    p1234569
22  ABC22   First   Last    p1234570
23  ABC23   First   Last    p1234571
24  ABC24   First   Last    p1234572
25  ABC25   First   Last    p1234573
26  ABC26   First   Last    p1234574
27  ABC27   First   Last    p1234575
28  ABC28   First   Last    p1234576
29  ABC29   First   Last    p1234577
30  ABC30   First   Last    p1234578
31  ABC31   First   Last    p1234579
32  ABC32   First   Last    p1234580
33          First   Last    p1234581
34  ABC34   First   Last    p1234582
35          First   Last    p1234583
36  ABC36   First   Last    p1234584
37          First   Last    p1234585
38  ABC38   First   Last    p1234586
39          First   Last    p1234587
40  ABC40   First   Last    p1234588
41          First   Last    p1234589
42  ABC42   First   Last    p1234590
43          First   Last    p1234591
44  ABC44   First   Last    p1234592
45          First   Last    p1234593
46  ABC46   First   Last    p1234594
47          First   Last    p1234595
48  ABC48   First   Last    p1234596
49          First   Last    p1234597
50  ABC50   First   Last    p1234598
51          First   Last    p1234599
52  ABC52   First   Last    p1234600
53          First   Last    p1234601
54  ABC54   First   Last    p1234602
55          First   Last    p1234603
56  ABC56   First   Last    p1234604
57          First   Last    p1234605
58  ABC58   First   Last    p1234606
59          First   Last    p1234607
60  ABC60   First   Last    p1234608
61          First   Last    p1234609
62  ABC62   First   Last    p1234610
63          First   Last    p1234611
64  ABC64   First   Last    p1234612
65          First   Last    p1234613
66          First   Last    p1234614
67          First   Last    p1234615
68  ABC68   First   Last    p1234616
69          First   Last    p1234617
70          First   Last    p1234618
71          First   Last    p1234619
72  ABC72   First   Last    p1234620
73          First   Last    p1234621
74          First   Last    p1234622
75          First   Last    p1234623
76  ABC76   First   Last    p1234624
77          First   Last    p1234625
78          First   Last    p1234626
79          First   Last    p1234627
80  ABC80   First   Last    p1234628
81          First   Last    p1234629
82          First   Last    p1234630
83          First   Last    p1234631
84  ABC84   First   Last    p1234632
85          First   Last    p1234633
86          First   Last    p1234634
87          First   Last    p1234635
88  ABC88   First   Last    p1234636
89          First   Last    p1234637
90          First   Last    p1234638
91          First   Last    p1234639
92  ABC92   First   Last    p1234640
93          First   Last    p1234641
94          First   Last    p1234642
95          First   Last    p1234643
96  ABC96   First   Last    p1234644
97          First   Last    p1234645
98          First   Last    p1234646
99          First   Last    p1234647
100 ABC100  First   Last    p1234648
```

I am using a standard import syntax:

```
GET DATA
  /TYPE=XLS
  /FILE='Y:\RESEARCH UNIT\RESEARCH UNIT PROJECTS\DATA\2016\Quarter 1 (Jan - Mar 2016)\Working Files\WK-FILE ONE.xls'
  /SHEET=name 'Demographics'
  /CELLRANGE=full
  /READNAMES=on
  /ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=32767.
```

The only clue I have is the excel formula that creates the ID_1 is "=CONCATENATE(G1,F1,A1)". SPSS hasn't had any issues with importing other formula based values, but maybe I am missing something.

Thanks in advance for anyone with a theory on what is happening and a way to fix it that doesn't involve manually altering the original excel files!

Comment: is it possible you have some non-printable characters in those cells in Excel ? Also, is the excel a "true" excel file, or is it based on something else, like a text or csv file ?

Comment: It is a true excel file in "excel 97 compatible" XLS format. The only data in that column is the formula concatenating an ID number... and it has the same glitch across a variety of files built off the same template starting with case # 33 being missing

Comment: And just to be sure: you have the same formula in all cells in that column ? And are the IDs posted here the ones you have in your file, or have you posted some dummy IDs ?

Comment: yes, the identical formula. However, different files have different IDs but it is always 33, 35 and so on that show up blank, even if the ID is completely different. as for the ID numbers, I am using dummy data here due to confidentiality issues. However if there isn't an actual case and it pulls in a default dummy ID it shows "ART" instead fo ABC i.e., ART32 (ART33 is missing) ART34 (ART35 is missing)

Comment: Are you sure you do not have any non-printable characters in the IDs in Excel texts which get concatenated ? Have you tried putting some other strings  int the cells which get concatenated ? Do you get the same errors ?
Just throwing ideas against the wall, maybe something sticks...

Comment: I tried playing around with changing things up, and it is definitely something wrong with importing the concatenation formula and the 97 compatible file type. If I convert the column to text (copy and paste values only) it resolves. I also tried saving and opening the file as an XLSX file, which also worked-the error resolves.

Comment: UNICODE might have something to do with it. Use 'SHOW UNICODE.' to see what is currently being used (you can also see at the bottom of the syntax window). Then 'SET UNICODE ON/OFF.' will change it for you. The command won't work if there is a non-empty dataset open.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Statistics are you using?  Have you installed the latest fixpack for it?  Excel files are endlessly tricky.

Comment: IBM SPSS 23. I'm not sure what updates come with the package my employer bought, but there's some ~$1500 customer support feature.

Comment: I think fixpacks are available to everyone.  Look here.   https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/options?selectionBean.selectedTab=find&selection=SPSS%3bibm%2fInformation+Management%2fSPSS+Statistics

Comment: I will try getting that fix pack installed and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: You could also send me the file to experiment with (jkpeck@gmail.com)

Comment: Sadly the original file is full of confidential information that I cannot distribute. I might be able to strip it down and see if I can send you something that still has the same error.

Comment: To close this out, converting the file to xlsx resolved the problem.

Comment: In the above code i see: `/TYPE=XLS` as well as `/ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=32767.` The latter makes no sense for .xls 1997-2003 files, given the limitations of the .xls file type. Using formulas in .xls files and importing in spss is tricky, because formulas are often long and can easily fill up a cell, especially when referencing data in other xls files.
I'm curious if the spreadsheet has cells with too many characters. This could explain the empty cells (possibly empty because of preceding cell?).